# Postgres Query for Beginners

Tags: postgresql

Ok, I deleted previous post and will try this again.  I am sure I don't know the topic and I'm not sure if this is a loop or if I should use a stored function or how to get what I'm looking for.  Here's sample data and expected output;

I have a single table A.  Table has following fields; date created, unique person key, type, location.

I need a Postgres query that says for any given month(parameter, based on *date created*) and given a *location*(parameter based on *location* field), provide me fieds below where *unique person key* may be duplicated + or – 30 days from the *date created* within the month given for same *type* but all *locations*.

Example Data

```
    Date Created | Unique Person  |  Type   |  Location
    ---------------------------------------------------
     2/5/2017    |   1            |  Admit  |  Hospital1
     2/6/2017    |   2            |  Admit  |  Hospital2
     2/15/2017   |   1            |  Admit  |  Hospital2
     2/28/2017   |   3            |  Admit  |  Hospital2
     3/3/2017    |   2            |  Admit  |  Hospital1
     3/15/2017   |   3            |  Admit  |  Hospital3
     3/20/2017   |   4            |  Admit  |  Hospital1
     4/1/2017    |   1            |  Admit  |  Hospital2
```

Output for the month of March for Hospital1:

```
    DateCreated| UniquePerson | Type | Location | +-30days | OtherLoc.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     3/3/2017  |    2         | Admit| Hospital1 | 2/6/2017   | Hospital2
```

Output for the month of March for Hospital2:

```
    None, because no one was seen at Hospital2 in March
```

Output for the month of March for Hospital3:

```
    DateCreated| UniquePerson | Type | Location | +-30days | otherLoc.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     3/15/2017 |   3          | Admit| Hospital3 | 2/28/2017  | Hospital2
```

Answer (score 2):

**Version 1**

I would use a `WITH` clause. Please, notice that I've added a column `id` that is a primary key to simplify the query. It's just to prevent the rows to be matched with themselves.

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        date_created,
        unique_person_id,
        type,
        location
    FROM
        a
    WHERE
        location = 'Hospital1' AND
        date_trunc('month', date_created) = date_trunc('month', '2017-03-01'::date)
)
SELECT
    x.date_created,
    x.unique_person_id,
    x.type,
    x.location,
    a.date_created AS "+-30days",
    a.location AS other_location
FROM
    x
    JOIN a
    USING (unique_person_id, type)
WHERE
    x.id != a.id AND
    abs(x.date_created - a.date_created) <= 30;
```

Now a little bit of explanations:

- First we select, let's say a reference data with a `WITH` clause. Think of it as a temporary table that we can reference in the main query. In given example it could be a "main visit" in given hospital.
- Then we join "main visits" with other visits of the same person and type (`JOIN` condition) that happen in date difference of 30 days (`WHERE` condition).

Notice that the `WITH` query has the limits you want to check (location and date). I use `date_trunc` function that truncates the date to specified precision (a month in this case).

---

**Version 2**

As [@Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) suggested, there is no special need to use a `WITH` clause. Right, so here is a second version.

```
SELECT
    x.date_created,
    x.unique_person_id,
    x.type,
    x.location,
    a.date_created AS "+-30days",
    a.location AS other_location
FROM
    a AS x
    JOIN a
    USING (unique_person_id, type)
WHERE
    x.location = 'Hospital1' AND
    date_trunc('month', x.date_created) = date_trunc('month', '2017-03-01'::date) AND
    x.id != a.id AND
    abs(x.date_created - a.date_created) <= 30;
```

This version is shorter than the first one but, in my opinion, the first is easier to understand. I don't have big enough set of data to test and I wonder which one runs faster (the query planner shows similar values for both).

Comment: I don't see a need for a `WITH` clause, why don't you just join `a` with itself and apply the contitions in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - you're right. I've added second query without `WITH` clause. I find my first version easier to understand, but maybe `WITH` is not for a beginner (as OP stated in the title). Thanks for the comment.